# Remove from dataframe unique rows

Tags: pyspark

I have such problem: i need to remove rows that have in the column A unique values from dataframe

In example below of the DF1 row 0 and 3 should be removed

```
        A      B       C
0       5    100       5
1       1    200       5
2       1    150       4
3       3    500       5
```

The one solution that I thought till now it is:

1. groupby(A)
2. count rows in each group
3. filter out counts > 1
4. save result into DF2
5. DF1.intersect(DF2)

any other ideas? solution for RDD also can help, but better for DataFrame 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more condensed syntax (but following same approach):

```
df=sqlContext.createDataFrame([[5,100,5],[1,200,5],[1,150,4],[3,500,5]],['A','B','C'])
df.registerTempTable('df') # Making SQL queries possible
df_t=sqlContext.sql('select A,count(B) from df group by A having count(B)=1') # step 1 to 4 in 1 statement
df2=df.join(df_t,df.A==df_t.A,'leftsemi') # only keep records that have a matching key
```

Some people refer to the 'leftsemi' as 'left keep'. It keeps records of dataframe 1 if the key also exists in df_t.